# Chrome fonts too narrow and line spacing too big

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

My Chrome fonts are too narrow and line spacing is too big:

[image: Chrome fonts too narrow and line spacing too big]

How do change the settings to make it display the fonts properly? By the way, this issue is not related to fonts size type of thing though. Any ideas?

Edit: Is this due to certain font-family style? I've found `arial,sans-serif` in multiple places upon inspecting the webpage in Chrome.

Comment: Select a bit of the text, right-click, choose "Inspect...". A new window (or pane) will open. In the right-hand column, scroll down until you find the property "font-family". What does it say?

Comment: In the 'Elements' tab of the top-right panel, I found no such thing as 'font-family' unfortunately. However, I did find one ( `arial,sans-serif` ) under the 'Styles' tab in the bottom-right panel, with some other those keywords in strike-through text style. Hope that would be helpful.

Comment: `arial, sans-serif`is the expected font on Google search pages. Did you install the Microsoft core fonts? Check with `fc-match Arial`; it should say something like `Arial.ttf`. If not, do `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, press OK to agree to the license agreement, then do `sudo fc-cache`. You need to restart Chrome to have any effect.

Comment: That's good to know, and yet `fc-match Arial` throws me `ARIALN.TTF: "Arial" "Narrow"`. Is that weird? The `ttf-mscorefonts-installer is already the newest version (3.4+nmu1ubuntu2)` is what I got upon entering your next line. lol

Comment: Ah, there is your problem: you use font substitution so the Arial font is substituted by Arial Narrow.

Comment: Is there anything in your `~/.fontconfig` folder?

Comment: Yea. But sadly I don't see that hidden folder under the home directory. Should I go create one?

Comment: No, but press Crtl H in the file manager to show hidden files.

Comment: Well, it turned out that I incorrectly installed`ttf-mscorefonts-installer` before. After uninstalling and reinstalling it, I managed to get `Arial.ttf: "Arial" "Regular"` as expected. Thank you very much for your great help. I can't appreciate it enough. :D

Comment: @Jos Can you please write an answer?

Answer (score 2):

My solution is simple but mostly credited to @Jos.

Make sure `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` is installed correctly in the system. If not, uninstall and reinstall it with the following commands.

1. `sudo dpkg -P ttf-mscorefonts-installer`
2. `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`
3. Use `TAB` and `Enter` keys to navigate the installing process.
4. `sudo fc-cache`

And it should work properly now. But It may not apply to everybody else's situation though.